# Sencha Touch - How to remove/hide popup panel on button click

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, modalpopups

I have created Panel as bellow

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.DatePanel', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
alias: 'widget.DatePanel',
config: {
    itemid:'DatePanel',
    modal:true,
    centered: true,
    width:'320px',
    height:'110px',   
    items:[
            {
                xtype: 'datepickerfield',
                label: 'Select date',
                type:'date',
                itemId: 'rptDate',
                value: new Date(),
            },
            {
                xtype:'toolbar',
                docked:'bottom',
                items:[{
                    text:'OK',
                    ui:'confirm',
                    action:'ShowTurnOverReport'
                },
                {
                    text:'Cancel',
                    ui:'confirm',
                    action:'Cancel'
                }

            }
        ]
}
```

});

I show this panel as Pop-up using bellow code

```
Ext.Viewport.add({xtype: 'DatePanel'});
```

Now on Button cancel click i want to hide/remove it

I have tried

```
Ext.Viewport.remove(Datepanel), 
var pnl = Ext.getCmp('DatePanel');
pnl.hide();
```

but nothing worked. how can i do this ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do it in multiple ways.

## Solution 1:

To use the `Ext.getCmp()` functionality, you need to have an `id` property set for your component.

Hence, give an `id` to your `DatePanel` like shown below,

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.DatePanel', {
extend: 'Ext.Panel',
alias: 'widget.DatePanel',
id:'datepanel',
config: {
     ......
     ......
```

and then on `Cancel` button click handler, write the below code ...

```
{
 text:'Cancel',
 ui:'confirm',
 action:'Cancel'
 listeners : {
     tap : function() {
           var pnl = Ext.getCmp('datepanel');
           pnl.hide();
     }
 }
}
```

## Solution 2:

Since you already defined the `itemid` property, you can use the following line to get the reference to your component ..

```
var pnl = Ext.Container.getComponent('DatePanel');
pnl.hide();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot its work fine with var pnl = Ext.getCmp('datepanel');           pnl.hide();. but one issue was there it gives warning when i again open this panel like (Please ensure the existing component has been destroyed) so i used pnl.destroy(); instead pnl.hide();

Comment: You can use itemId instead of id. And then identify component using Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#yourItemId')[0];